# Using VoiceOver for PDFs

Tags: ios, pdf, voiceover

I am currently looking for a way to have a PDF read back to the user similar to what VoiceOver does.

Is there a way to use voice over within my app to get it to read back pdfs or is there another pdf viewer that can do this for me.

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about programming or finding an app that suits your needs? Stack Overflow is a place for questions about programmers.

Comment: It is about programming. Hence Im asking for help integrating something into my app

Answer (score 0):

For accessibility purposes, Adobe Reader can do this natively. The user invokes the menu item View < Read Out Loud < Activate Read Out Loud in Adobe Reader before opening a file, then they open the file, and choose the scope -- whether they just want to hear the page they're on, or the entire document.

[image: menu screen shot]

Comment: This is good to know but I need this adobe reader to intergrate with an app.

Comment: Can this be done with selected text? So if I highlight a section of text can it just read that?

Comment: No, it won't read an individual selection. I suspect that's because this is an accessibility feature, and making a selection requiring vision is not supported. There seem to be only two controls - set scope, and turn the feature off/on. It sounds like you're looking for something more targeted.